# Export a React Components HTML,CSS & JS via an NextJS API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

i try to export an react components HTML, CSS, JS to implement it in another webpage.

**Our System**

1. NextJS (a header component with scss modules)
2. Spryker PHP based Webshop

**How we style right now**

```
import styles from "./Header.module.scss"
```

and then use it like this:

```
<div className={styles.hamburgerInner} />
```

sometimes we also have hardcoded classes like:

```
<div className={`col-auto order-3 ${styles.sbHeaderInfoIcons}`}>
```

inside the scss we also have variables:

```
background-color: $white;
```

which we import inside the Header.module.scss like this:

```
@import "src/styles/settings";
```

inside the settings we also have more imports where the variables and stuff are:

```
/**
 *  Settings
 * -----------------------------------------
 *  Globally used functions, Mixins, Variables
 */

@import "functions/respond-to";
@import "functions/z-index";
@import "mixins/placeholder";
@import "mixins/pseudo";
@import "mixins/read-more";
@import "mixins/transition";
@import "mixins/typography";
@import "mixins/icon-map";
@import "mixins/rem";
@import "mixins/spacer";
@import "variables/breakpoints";
@import "variables/colors";
@import "variables/bootstrap";
@import "helper/spacing";
@import "helper/is-loading";
@import "helper/overlay";
```

**Our Problem we want to solve**

we now want to use components from system 1 in system 2 to not have to write the header components in both languages everytime we have changes here.

**Problems we are facing while trying to find a solution**

we cant render react directly inside spryker, because it is not serverside rendered and we have to keep SEO in mind here.

the only solution we came up with is to find a way to just get the HTML, CSS & JS from react to then just implement it there and "paste" the code. we would achieve it while using the api functionality from nextjs, so that system 2 can just call this api to get the contents

do you guys know of a solution for this, especially if we use css modules here?

**What we already tryed**

we already tryed to use reacts "renderToString" method but here we dont get the css because of the modules, only the html and also there is no way to get the logic of the component (the JS part).

rendering react directly in spryker is not possible because it got rendered in the client and we need SSR here because we have to keep SEO in mind. that also eliminates an iframe solution.

Comment: How do you add your styles? is it stand alone files or styled component or something else?

Comment: wow, thank you pretty much for your fast reply! What I forgot to mention here is that we use scss modules here like: 

import styles from "./Header.module.scss"

and then use it like this: 
<div className={styles.hamburgerInner} />

sometime we also have hardcoded classes like: 

<div className={`col-auto order-3 ${styles.sbHeaderInfoIcons}`}>

Comment: i changed the question to also mention the scss part here, sorry

Comment: and yes we have a file laying in our repo : "Header.module.scss"